# Setting icon of folder on a removable drive automatically?

Tags: windows, ssd, icons, files-folders

Is there a way to change the icon of a folder on a removable drive automatically?
I have a ton of folders on it, and I changed all the icons. The icon files I used were on the drive, but when I unplugged and reconnected the drive, the icons were gone.

I know you can change the icon of the drive, but that isn't the issue here.

But is there a way to modify the `desktop.ini` to change the icon of a folder on a drive automatically on different computers? If not, is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: autorun.inf is for the drive.. desktop.ini is for customizing folders and has different syntax.  You would think that the explorer team would have done a better job making the same mechanism for both.  Right click a folder -> properties -> customize -> Change icon.  Then look at the generated desktop.ini so you know what change "by hand" next time. :)   I told you to do it that way so I didn't have to tell you every field and how to populate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Changing the icons of folders automatically

There are several ways to achieve this. First off, know that `autorun.inf` is for the drive, not folders. To do it for a folder, you would create a file called `desktop.ini`. You would place that file inside the folder you want to change the icon of, and put in the following code.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=.\NAME.ico,0
```

Replacing "`name`" with the name of the file. The reason it works on some devices and not on others is because of the drive letters. When plugging a drive into your computer, it should automatically be assigned a letter, for instance, the default windows path is `C:`.
The default generated `destop.ini` is programmed something like the following:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=E:\Applications\icon.ico,0
```

and if a different computer assigned it a different path, it would, therefore not exist unless you change the drive icon. (Instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-drive-letter).)

Tips:

1. Hide the `desktop.ini` file by selecting the file, going to view, and clicking "hide
   selected items."
2. If you create your own `desktop.ini` file, it sometimes may not work. In that case, right-click the folder and click "Change icon" and edit the generated `desktop.ini`. Make sure to turn "show hidden items" on!
3. If you want to check if you did everything correctly, you can [assign it to a different path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-drive-letter) and see if all the icons are in place.

Happy Holidays!

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

Though the above answer is correct, you don't have to create a desktop.ini yourself.
There are far simpler methods to achieve that, just use the GUI method and explorer will create a desktop.ini for you automatically;

Though you already know these steps, there are other people who don't know;

Left click on a folder whose icon you want to change, right click to bring up context menu, click "Properties", scroll down if it's not showing.

Then in Properties menu, click "Customize" tab and click "Change Icon..."
[image]

To bring up this menu:

[image]

You can then either browse for the icon or type in address bar, there is auto-complete feature in the address bar, so you can just type part of the path and choose the suggestions by arrow keys up and down, then press \ and repeat until the path to the icon is complete; Then click "OK", "Apply" and "OK" and Explorer will create a desktop.ini located inside the folder(it's hidden, you have to make explorer show hidden files to see it.)

This method is far more human friendly, now if the icons displayed are not what you chose when you connect the drive to a different computer, that is because the drive letter is different, change the drive letter and the icons displayed would be what you chose again;

In fact, changing drive letter should be the first thing when you connect the external drive to another computer, it can be down by following these steps:

First, open Explorer, open "This PC", if openning Explorer doesn't show "This PC", in the left pane, find and click "This PC", check which drive is your external drive by either using volume name or volume size, remember its drive letter.

Open elevated Command Prompt by using either one of the three methods:

1, Task Manger

Ctrl+Alt+Del to bring up security options, click "Task Manager", click "File"->"Run new task"->type cmd->click "Create this task with administrative privileges" checkbox->"OK"

2, Create a desktop shortcut

right click on Desktop->"New"->"Shortcut"->type %comspec%->press "Enter"->press "Enter", then right click on cmd.exe.lnk->"Properties"->"Advanced..."->check "Run as administrator"->"OK"->"Apply"->"OK" (if there is a pop up window just hit "OK"), then double click the shortcut. By using this method you can just double click on the shortcut on desktop the next time you want to run cmd, or drag it to taskbar and you only need single click to run it.

3, use run menu

Win+R->type cmd->Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Use the following commands to change drive letter:

```
diskpart
list volume
```

you have to find which volume is the external drive by its letter, in this example, the volume is volume 2:

```
select Volume 2
```

Then you just have to assign its letter to the old letter in the old computer, in this example, the letter is F(you have to replace it):

```
assign letter=F
```

Then run `list volume` again to confirm change, close cmd, open explorer, press F5 and see the change...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however the question was to do it automatically, not manually. Better luck next time! :)